# SQL query to retrieve data between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've written following code:

```
Dim date1 As Date
Dim date2 As Date

date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DatePickerFromDate.Text)
date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(DatePickerToDate.Text)

Dim cnd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE Invoice_Date BETWEEN " + date1 + "  AND  " + date2 + "", om)
om.Open()
Dim da As OleDbDataReader = cnd.ExecuteReader
While da.Read()
      ComboBox1.Items.Add(da(0))
End While
da.Close()
om.Close()
```

I want to retrieve data between two dates that are been taken from two datepickers.

I tried BETWEEN, also i tried >= =< but result was empty though database contains data. Please help where I'm getting wrong

Comment: Why is this tagged with both MySQL and SQL Server?  Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is probably generating an error.  When doing this type of querying, you should store the query string *after* substitution and print it out.  You seem to be missing delimiters around the dates.  So this may work in your specific case.

```
New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE Invoice_Date BETWEEN '" + date1 + "'  AND  '" + date2 + "'", om)
```

However, you then need to be careful about the format of the dates.  The application layer and the database might use different formats.  If you are substituting directly into the query string, then use the format YYYY-MM-DD -- it is the ISO standard date format and generally understood.

Even better is to learn how to parameterize queries so you can actually pass in the date values as date parameters.

Comment: Rather than getting an error, what I've seen happen is a date like 1/15/2014 gets evaluated as 1 divided by 15 divided by 2014, which comes out to zero. Then zero is happily treated as the date '1/1/1900' (at least for `datetime`)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff : I've used MM/DD/YYYY format. The Invoice_Date is of datatype Date, when i'm passing query with delimiters its displaying an error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Comment: @John Gibb : Ya, its not displaying any error. May be the problem is what you said. So do you have any solutions for the problem, i mean what modifications shall i do in the query

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS Access, this should be the syntax...

```
SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE Invoice_Date>=#" + date1 + "# and Invoice_Date<=#" + date2 + "#"
```

If you're using MS SQL Server or MySQL, then do something like this...

```
 SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE Invoice_Date>='" + date1 + "' and Invoice_Date<='" + date2 + "'"
```