# SQL query for selecting data from a table where date between and time between

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT train_name 
FROM train 
WHERE Date BETWEEN and time between
```

I want some suggestion for the SQL query where I can select data from the any table like train having train no, name, from, to, and time.

I want to select trains from the train table between two dates and between the specific time.

I will be very thankful to you for the help

Comment: Where are you stuck? Also, post your table structure.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140494/sql-query-to-retrieve-data-between-two-dates.

Comment: Use this condition to check date between 2 intervals `Where Date >= Interval1 and Date < Interval2`

Comment: Your current code looks fine just fill in the dates and times i.e. `Date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-01' AND Time BETWEEN '12:00' AND '14:00'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT train_name 
FROM train 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2014-10-11 10:00:00' AND '2014-10-11 11:00:00'
```

**OR**

```
SELECT train_name 
FROM train 
WHERE Date > '2014-10-11 10:00:00' AND Date < '2014-10-11 11:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

select  train_name from train where Date between '2014-02-10 00:00:00' and '2014-02-10 23:59:59';